# how to stop empty object in useState?

Tags: reactjs

Whenever I call for the useState variable inside the functional component of react, before return section, if I set an array/object with values in useState, it always sends me an empty array/object. As a result, whenever I map it, it sends undefined. I want to wait for the value to come first without getting an empty value. how to do it?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './HomeBike.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import MyOrder from '../../MyOrder/MyOrder';
const Home = (props) => {
    const [shel, setShel] = useState([]);

    setShel(['friend', 'sath']);
    console.log(shel);

    const { name, s_details, image, _id } = props.service;



    return (
        <div>
            <div className="col h-100">
                <div className="card h-100">
                    <img src={image} className="card-img-top service-img" alt="..." />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">{name}</h5>
                        <p className="card-text">{s_details}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-footer">
                        <div className="d-grid gap-2">
                            <Link to={`/details/${_id}`}>
                                <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button">Pucrchase Details</button>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: What the excelly issue you fetching ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React `this.setState`, and `React.useState` create queues for React core to update the state object of a React component.

So the process to update React state is asynchronous for performance reasons. That’s why changes don’t feel immediate.

```
const Home = (props) => {
    const [shel, setShel] = useState(['friend', 'sath']);
    console.log(shel);

    const { name, s_details, image, _id } = props.service;

    return (
        <div>
         <Your code...>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```